# Visual Studio Code Highlighting for Angular Syntax in HTML

Tags: html, angular, syntax, visual-studio-code, highlighting

I'm using vs code with angular.
Is there a any way to colorize angular syntax in html.

For example this image;

[image]

Comment: I have installed:Angular 5 Snippets from John Papa and Angular Language Service, see that these extension help you

Comment: Thanks for your comment. İ already install these extensions but nothing change in html file

Comment: The plugin i have been developing will do that https://github.com/ghaschel/vscode-angular-html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tryed that extension its great but not excaly what i need. i want to customize colors whatever i want. I dont know is it possible

Comment: As far as I know, the only way you're going to be able to do such thing is creating your own vscode theme

Comment: @HasanGundogdu you can do it now using vscode-angular-html. Please check the docs